# How can I set audit controls on files owned by TrustedInstaller using Powershell?

Tags: windows-7, permissions, powershell, audit

I am trying to set audit controls on a number of files (listed in `ACLsWin.txt`) located in `\%Windows%\System32` (for example, `aaclient.dll`) using the following Powershell script:

```
$FileList = Get-Content ".\ACLsWin.txt"
$ACL = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSecurity

$AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAuditRule("Everyone", "Delete", "Failure")
$ACL.AddAuditRule($AccessRule)
foreach($File in $FileList)
{
    Write-Host "Changing audit on $File"
    $ACL | Set-Acl $File
}
```

Whenever I run the script, I get the error `PermissionDenied [Set-Acl] UnauthorizedAccessException`.

This seems to come from the fact that the owner of these files is `TrustedInstaller`. I am running these scripts as Administrator (even though I'm on the the built-in Administrator account) and it's still failing. I can set these audit controls by hand using the Security tab, but there are at least 200 files for which doing by hand may lead to human errors.

How can I get around `TrustedInstaller` and set these audit controls using Powershell?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only supported way to modify files that are protected by Windows Resource Protection (which the TrustedInstaller account is a part of WRP,) is to use the Windows Module Installer service, which is really just a way of saying "you cannot modify these files in a supported way yourself; only through installing patches and service packs can these files be modified in a supported way."

The `sfc.exe` utility is also part of Windows Resource Protection.  Using `sfc.exe` you can that the file has been modified, and it will replace it with a copy from the WinSxS store.

You would *have* to take ownership of these files yourself before you can modify them.  The easiest way to do that is with `takeown.exe`.

But the fact of the matter is you're not supposed to be modifying these files.

Application developers can use the `SfcIsFileProtected` or `SfcIsKeyProtected` APIs to check whether a file is or isn't under the protection of WRP.

<strike>The reason why I wouldn't write a script for someone to do this is because it's not supported to modify these files, and as a professional, I couldn't in good conscience help someone get their system into an unsupported state. ;)</strike> Edit: Damnit, I just did...

Edit: If you still insist on hacking it, then technically one option is to [launch `Powershell.exe` using the security token of `TrustedInstaller.exe`.](http://vorck.com/windows/ntauth.html)

Or, the easier thing to do would be to write a script with a Try/Catch block, and if the catch block is triggered by an `[UnauthorizedAccessException]`, then take ownership of the file and try again.

```
C:\Windows\system32>takeown /A /F C:\Windows\System32\aaclient.dll

SUCCESS: The file (or folder): "C:\Windows\System32\aaclient.dll" now owned by the administrators group.
```

You can also monitor modifications to these files using a filter driver. This is how things such as antivirus products accomplish it. But uh... that's probably more work than you want to do at the moment...

Edit again!: Oh, you want to set the owner back to TrustedInstaller afterwards? You need the `SeRestorePrivilege` privilege for that.

Copy paste this to .\Enable-Privilege.ps1:

```
Function Enable-Privilege 
{
 param([ValidateSet("SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege", "SeAuditPrivilege", "SeBackupPrivilege",
   "SeChangeNotifyPrivilege", "SeCreateGlobalPrivilege", "SeCreatePagefilePrivilege",
   "SeCreatePermanentPrivilege", "SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege", "SeCreateTokenPrivilege",
   "SeDebugPrivilege", "SeEnableDelegationPrivilege", "SeImpersonatePrivilege", "SeIncreaseBasePriorityPrivilege",
   "SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege", "SeIncreaseWorkingSetPrivilege", "SeLoadDriverPrivilege",
   "SeLockMemoryPrivilege", "SeMachineAccountPrivilege", "SeManageVolumePrivilege",
   "SeProfileSingleProcessPrivilege", "SeRelabelPrivilege", "SeRemoteShutdownPrivilege",
   "SeRestorePrivilege", "SeSecurityPrivilege", "SeShutdownPrivilege", "SeSyncAgentPrivilege",
   "SeSystemEnvironmentPrivilege", "SeSystemProfilePrivilege", "SeSystemtimePrivilege",
   "SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege", "SeTcbPrivilege", "SeTimeZonePrivilege", "SeTrustedCredManAccessPrivilege",
   "SeUndockPrivilege", "SeUnsolicitedInputPrivilege")]$Privilege,
  $ProcessId = $pid,
  [Switch]$Disable)

   $Definition = @'
 using System;
 using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

 public class AdjPriv
 {
  [DllImport("advapi32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
  internal static extern bool AdjustTokenPrivileges(IntPtr htok, bool disall,
   ref TokPriv1Luid newst, int len, IntPtr prev, IntPtr relen);

  [DllImport("advapi32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
  internal static extern bool OpenProcessToken(IntPtr h, int acc, ref IntPtr phtok);
  [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
  internal static extern bool LookupPrivilegeValue(string host, string name, ref long pluid);
  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
  internal struct TokPriv1Luid
  {
   public int Count;
   public long Luid;
   public int Attr;
  }

  internal const int SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED = 0x00000002;
  internal const int SE_PRIVILEGE_DISABLED = 0x00000000;
  internal const int TOKEN_QUERY = 0x00000008;
  internal const int TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES = 0x00000020;
  public static bool EnablePrivilege(long processHandle, string privilege, bool disable)
  {
   bool retVal;
   TokPriv1Luid tp;
   IntPtr hproc = new IntPtr(processHandle);
   IntPtr htok = IntPtr.Zero;
   retVal = OpenProcessToken(hproc, TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, ref htok);
   tp.Count = 1;
   tp.Luid = 0;
   if(disable)
   {
    tp.Attr = SE_PRIVILEGE_DISABLED;
   }
   else
   {
    tp.Attr = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
   }
   retVal = LookupPrivilegeValue(null, privilege, ref tp.Luid);
   retVal = AdjustTokenPrivileges(htok, false, ref tp, 0, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
   return retVal;
  }
 }
'@


 $ProcessHandle = (Get-Process -id $ProcessId).Handle
 $type = Add-Type $definition -PassThru
 $type[0]::EnablePrivilege($processHandle, $Privilege, $Disable)

}
```

In Powershell, dot-source Enable-Privilege.ps1 like so:

```
PS C:\> . .\Enable-Privilege.ps1

PS C:\> [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]$TrustedInstaller = "NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller"
```

Save the current ACL:

```
PS C:\> $ACL = Get-Acl C:\Windows\System32\aaclient.dll
```

Change the owner to TrustedInstaller:

```
PS C:\> $ACL.SetOwner($TrustedInstaller)
```

Enable the SeRestorePrivilege:

```
PS C:\> Enable-Privilege SeRestorePrivilege
```

Re-apply the modified ACL. This is the part that will fail, even for the Local System account, if you do not explicitly set the SeRestorePrivilege privilege:

```
PS C:\> Set-Acl -Path C:\Windows\System32\aaclient.dll -AclObject $ACL
```

[I shameless stole the Enable-Privilege function from this TechNet Forums thread.](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/e718a560-2908-4b91-ad42-d392e7f8f1ad/take-ownership-of-a-registry-key-and-change-permissions?forum=winserverpowershell)

Comment: I do insist on "hacking" these files because it is a requirement that these files be watched for failed attempted modifications by users, usually indicative of someone doing things they should not be doing, or a system level compromise. If I could leave these files alone, I would, but unfortunately that is not the case.

Comment: I've also attempted to take ownership of the file using `$ACL.SetOwner("BUILTIN\Administrators")` but I get the same error `UnauthorizedAccessException`.

Comment: Run from an elevated process, and use e.g. `takeown /A /F C:\Windows\System32\aaclient.dll`

Comment: TakeOwn worked great. Is there a way to set it back to TrustedInstaller once I've set my audits?